# where can I find and examine apt packages online

Tags: apt

I've installed samba4 beta 5 from sources. As a result there are some files missing that would be present in the apt package for ubuntu. /etc/default/samba4 for example.

I'd like to just copy these in from the apt package for samba4-alpha-18. Where can I find/examine the contents of this apt package?

Comment: Do you want the installation path  or the .deb packages.

Comment: I want to access text files in the deb packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [launchpad](http://launchpad.net), this is the site of the repositories for all packages of Ubuntu.

You can download in a tar.gz the packages from there.
Exemple : [samba4 latest version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/samba4/4.0.0~alpha18.dfsg1-4ubuntu2)

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Note that not all packages have their .tar.gz there.  They may have an orig.tar.gz, used for creating the package, but you'd need all parts of the source package to rebuild the package with modifications or additions/subtractions

Answer (score 3):

I see that Bruno's answer has already been accepted, but I suppose I should throw in my two cents.

One of my favorite tools is [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com). Using the search tool at the bottom of the page, I was able to find [the samba4 package in Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/samba4). From there, you can either download the .deb package and extract its contents, or you can simply look at [the file list online](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/samba4/filelist).

I hope that helps!